# flex paging datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, paging

i want to implement paging in flex datagrid, i am using [this](http://gurufaction.blogspot.com/2007/02/flex-datagrid-paging-example-with.html) code. In Asp.net we can implement paging by setting property of datagrid, is there any such property for flex datagrid?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not** implement Paging in Flex by setting any **property** in Flex provided grid as **Constantiner** said,

**but** by playing with Array/ArrayCollection as in your provider example,

there is another good [example](http://www.iamboredsoiblog.eu/2009/01/10/advanced-paging-and-filtering-in-flex-datagrid/)

or

you can use any **custom grid control** such as [FLEXICIOUS](http://www.flexicious.com/Home/IndexFlexicious), *an extension to the ADOBE FLEX DataGrid AND Advanced DataGrid controls*

Hpoes that helps

Answer (score 1):

`DataGrid` in Flex hasn't any built-in paging functionality.